# react-native-chart-kit error while updating property "d" of a view managed by RNSVGPath:

Tags: api, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I am using react-native-chart-kit pie chart.

In the data array, instead of writing a number in the population, I am writing “this.state.data” as shown below since I am getting the numbers from an API.

```
const pieData1 = [
  {
    name: ': East',
    population: this.state.data,
    color: '#00664f',
    legendFontColor: 'black',
    legendFontSize: 12,
  },
```

]

But I get the error "error while updating property "d" of a view managed by RNSVGPath:". Any idea how to solve it please?

Comment: Check for undefined variable data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just typecast your state to Integer using `parseInt`

```
const pieData1 = [
  {
    name: ': East',
    population: parseInt(this.state.data), ////
    color: '#00664f',
    legendFontColor: 'black',
    legendFontSize: 12,
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the thing is by default chart requires data other than empty.

just maintain some kind assign value in state.

Comment: you can post answers like this in the comment section below the question.

Comment: Great, That worked like a charm!! My mistake was, I was just defining blank variables initially in the constructor. Anyway, thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this is the fix for the issue.
I experienced same error on PieChart until I realized that property I pass to as a float turned out to be a string.
JavaScript is not strong typed language - hence adding parseFloat resolved the issue.